# Where to use ng-model in drop-down

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Where to use ng-model here? if I use with select tag it show first option blank and with  its not binding data.

```
<label style="margin-top:8%;" class="item item-input item-select">
  <div class="input-label">
    Menus&nbsp;
  </div>
  <select>
   <option ng-repeat="a in result.result">{{a.groupName}}</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select requires ng-model and shows the default option only when the value in ng-model matches with the one of the elements in the options.

see [select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) and [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) documentation.

so you need to use it like this,

In HTML,

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectValue" ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in availableOptions">
```

In app.js,

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.world = 'World';
  $scope.selectValue="2";
    $scope.availableOptions = [
      {id: '1', name: 'Option A'},
      {id: '2', name: 'Option B'},
      {id: '3', name: 'Option C'}
    ];
});
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QSndgB1XR1xPhbIulGdB?p=preview) link for the same.